# How to perform latent classification analysis for imperfect reference with absent gold standard? Do we need to check verification bias?

Tags: bayesian, classification, diagnosis

I have clinical data which lacks a golden standard for diagnosis. instead multiple indices are used with different accuracy. I have transformed the results from these indices to binary for with patient having and not having the disease. This is then used for latent classification analysis. I want to know if i should use all samples for this analysis? or should i divide them and then use remaining samples for validation? Also, will i need to check for verification bias and how do i select a method to do that? How to check category of each patient for diagnosis after that?

below is tabular form that i used to subject under latent classification analysis (LCA) using poLCA package in R | Patient_ID | Index 1 | Index2 |Index3 | | -------- | -------- |-------- -------- | | 1 | 1 |1 |2 | | 2 | 2 |2 |1 |

the results i get are

Fit for 2 latent classes:
number of observations: 65 number of estimated parameters: 7 residual degrees of freedom: 0 maximum log-likelihood: -116.6411

AIC(2): 247.2821 BIC(2): 262.5028 G^2(2): 0.3041395 (Likelihood ratio/deviance statistic) X^2(2): 0.291966 (Chi-square goodness of fit)

what type of graph will make me understand the results better? Thank you, your help will be appreciated here